# ASP.NET MVC 4, Web API - 404 not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2012

I know that ASP.NET MVC 4 can't route Web API in Areas (sic!).

I created for testing purposes new "Web API" project (in new solution) in Visual Studio 2012.

But it doesn't work. Default HomeController (Controller) works, but ValuesController (ApiController) is not found (404).

I have installed both VS 2010 and VS 2012.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you used the right URL? API controller routing is different from view controller routing by default. In the default project, the values controller is accessed by URL ~/api/Values, not ~/Values (as a view controller would be).

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC 4 can't route Web API in Areas **out of the box**. However, with a little bit of effort you can make it work: [Why are my Area specific Web API’s accessible from all other Areas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025347/why-are-my-area-specific-web-apis-accessible-from-all-other-areas)

Related blog post with more details [here](http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/).